# O Selenium já é Webdriver, não é?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Recentemente, após algumas análises eu tive que inserir a tag `selenium` em uma postagem que falava sobre automação web com Selenium, mas o editor também me sugeriu a tag [selenium-webdriver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), que ao meu ver é a mesma coisa da primeira.

Eu sugiro por fim em uma das tags, principalmente a [selenium-webdriver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), pois o Selenium já é de fato voltado à automação web, e nada além disso.

No site oficial do Selenium, é dito que:

> Selenium automates browsers. That's it! What you do with that power is entirely up to you.
>
> <sub>Retirado dia 03/04/2022 às 12h07 de https://www.selenium.dev/</sub>

Só para constar, no momento deste edit temos:

| Tag | Quantidade de perguntas |
| --- | --- |
| `selenium` | 344 |
| [selenium-webdriver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) | 234 |
| Overlap (perguntas com ambas) | 134 |
| Total (344 + 234 - 134) | 444 |

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135359/discussion-on-question-by-cypherpotato-o-selenium-ja-e-webdriver-nao-e), quem quiser acompanhar ou acrescentar alguma consideração pode seguir o link. A proposta foi aceita e será efetivada em breve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Está feito.

As postagens com a tag `selenium` agora estão com a tag [selenium-webdriver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver). As que possuíam ambas tags tiveram a tag `selenium` removida.

O wiki foi atualizado com informações das duas tags.